# laravel: function in model must return a relationship instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I try to build a path for a model on laravel

I created a function in my model:

```
public function path()
{
    return App\Helper\GeneralController::getURL($this);
}
```

with `dd(App\Helper\GeneralController::getURL($this))` test I got the right answer. (output is a URL)

but in view with the call: `$article->path`  I get this error:

> ```
> App\Article:: path must return a relationship instance.
> ```

What is wrong?

Comment: What url you want to get by `getURL` ? Did you check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#accessing-the-current-url) may be it help.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You need to call it:

```
$article->path()
```

When you do `$article->path`, you're trying to use Eloquent relationship which you don't have.

Comment: I actually was aware of this but simply didn't notice that I hadn't added "()" to my line of code. Thus, it was trying to access a property instead of executing a method. I was like "wtf am I doing wrong.." :'). Thanks for making me see the light.

Comment: Exactly. Where there is an eloquent relationship when you called a method's name ONLY from Model, it returns the object with relationship. However when there isn't an eloquent relationship, for example in this case the url string, the method has to be called as an ordinary php `method()`.

Answer (score 28):

I know this has already been answered and accepted. However, if the OP did want to use a property accessor rather than a method use the "get{property name}Attribute" syntax of Laravel to create a custom attribute.

Here is what it would look like for this specific case:

```
public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return App\Helper\GeneralController::getURL($this);
}
```

using this approach "path" can now be called as an attribute and will not be resolved to a relationship using the syntax:

```
$article->path;
```

Comment: Beautiful, along with all the other answers here there's the capacity to call it any way you could want but this is the reason I came to the thread. Thank you

Answer (score 17):

You're calling a relationship.

```
$article->path
```

To call the method, use '()', like so,

```
$article->path()
```

Answer (score 10):

I faced that error when I forgot to write **return** before relation in the model!
check it out now!

Answer (score 6):

`path()` is method not object element you need to call as method

```
$article->path();
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 9 introduced a new way to define accessors/mutators within a model using `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute`.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```php
public function path(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(fn () => GeneralController::getURL($this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors from Google, all the other answers can be applicable in certain scenarios, but you might want to also look if your method access modifier, if your method is `protected` and you try to call it you will be welcome with this error. You need change your method to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

For folks who encounter this error, if you created a custom attribute on model, you may want to check how did you call it, because if you declared a custom attribute as goes:

```php
getMyAwesomeThingAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->awsome + $this->thing;    
}
```

you should call it as follows:

```php
$model->my_awesome_thing;
```

but this is nono:

```php
$model->getMyAwesomeThingAttribute;
```