# Logic Exception: must return a relationship instance

Tags: php, laravel, twig

I am trying to use the following functions to display a stock level flag on using a Twig view template. But I am getting the following error:  LogicException
Cart\Models\Product::hasLowStock must return a relationship instance.
I've been researching this for a while and can't find a fix. I'm relatively new to php.

Here's my code:

```
namespace Cart\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function hasLowStock()
    {
        if($this->outOfStock()) {
            return false;
        }

        return (bool) $this->stock <= 5;
    }

    public function outOfStock()
    {
        return $this->stock === 0;
    }

    public function inStock()
    {
        return $this->stock >= 1;
    }

    public function hasStock($quantity)
    {
        return $this->stock >= $quantity;
    }
}
```

And here's the twig view I'm using to display the product/stock:
    {% extends 'templates/app.twig' %}

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="{{ product.title }} image." class="card img-fluid">
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {% if product.hasLowStock %}
                <span class="label label-warning">Low stock</span>
            {% endif %}

            {% if product.outOfStock %}
                <span class="label label-danger">Out of stock</span>
            {% endif %}

            {% if product.inStock %}
                <span class="label label-danger">Out of stock</span>
            {% endif %}
            <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant view code.

Comment: I just added the view code

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727381/laravel-function-in-model-must-return-a-relationship-instance . Looks like the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasLowStock()` etc. are methods, not properties:

```
{% if product.hasLowStock() %}
{% if product.outOfStock() %}
{% if product.inStock() %}
```

You can also use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
public function getHasLowStockAttribute()
{
    [...]
}
```

Then you can access them as properties:

```
{% if product.hasLowStock %}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the fix.